# Use DialogFlow with external API and with telegram

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I wanted to integrate Dialogflow with telegram-bot and external API, but to use external API in Dialogflow one needs to enable billing. So the question is if I enable billing, will I be charged to hit external API in Dialogflow fulfillment? If yes how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's clear up a misconception - you do **not** need to enable billing to use an external API. If you use the built-in fulfillment editor, you will be using Google Cloud Functions which may incur charges (more on that in a moment), but you do *not* need to use the built-in editor.

You can setup a web server anywhere you wish to handle your fulfillment webhook as long as it meets these two criteria:

1. It is at a publicly available IP address (ie - Google can reach it, it isn't behind a firewall or has a private address).
2. It can handle HTTPS POST requests not using a self-signed certificate.

So if you have your own server, or wish to run it on AWS, you don't need to enable billing.

If you *do* wish to use the built-in editor, and thus use Google Cloud Functions, you need to have billing enabled. However, this doesn't mean you'll be billed. There is a pretty generous [free-tier](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) for Google Cloud Functions which should be enough for your basic experiments and probably light usage. Once your code becomes more advanced - you should move it to something more directly under your control.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow doesn’t need to enable billing, you can do it, but you can skip this step if you are only using a free Dialogflow edition, please check the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/editions) to know more about the editions.

Regarding your question: Will I be charged to hit external API in Dialogflow fulfillment?

When using an external API, requests and end-user data are sent to both Google and the external API. The terms of service, SLA, pricing, and quotas for your agent edition are applicable for Google's handling of these requests. The external API's terms of service, SLA, pricing, and quotas are applicable for the external API's handling of these requests.

Having said that, Dialogflow is priced monthly based on the edition and the requests made during the month.

According with this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing#def) a request is defined as any call to the Dialogflow service, whether direct with API usage or indirect with integration or console usage.

Depending on the task and design of the agent, the number of requests needed for an end-user to accomplish a task with a Dialogflow agent can vary greatly.

You can consult the following [table](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing#table)  that provides a pricing comparison for editions, to create your own estimation depending on your needs.

On the other hand Dialogflow Standard Edition is free, there are limits on the amount of requests that you can make.  For more details, see [Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas).

Additionally I have found the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/telegram) that shows how to create a Dialogflow Telegram Integration.

I hope this information could be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)